# Поведение виртуальных функции в конструкторах и деструкторах

Tags: c++, virtual

Не могу понять почему "внутри конструкторов и деструкторов модификатор virtual теряет силу."

Я просмотрел несколько примеров - но так и не понял :(

В конструкторах нас не интересует наследуемые классы. Поведение и так понятно. Но Мейерс заострил на этом правиле внимание. Так что не так с виртуальными методами в конструкторах? Понятно, что читсый вирт метод не сможем вызвать... В общем не понял уникальности этой мысли

Comment: Где вы прочли, что в деструкторах `virtual` теряет силу?... хотелось бы понять контекст.

Answer (score 3):

В момент создания подъобъекта базового класса, подъобъект наследника еще не создан, поэтому в конструкторах и деструкторах виртуальная функция ведет себя как "обычная" функция-член.

```
struct Base
{
    Base() //Когда выполняется конструктор базового класса
    { //объект наследника еще не создан,
        foo();//т.е. у нас имеется только объект типа Base,
        //находящийся в процессе создания,
        //но его "внутренности" уже созданы,
        //собственно, поэтому и будет вызвана 
        //соответствующая функция из класса Base
    }
    virtual void foo();
};

struct Derived: 
    Base
{
    Derived(): 
        Base() //Сначала выполняется конструктор базового класса
        //При этом часть наследника еще не создана
    {
    }
    void foo() override;
};
```

> внутри конструкторов и деструкторов модификатор virtual теряет силу.

Стандарт по этому поводу говорит следующее:

> Member functions, including virtual functions (10.3), can be called during construction or destruction (12.6.2). When a virtual function is called directly or indirectly from a constructor or from a destructor, including during the construction or destruction of the class’s non-static data members, and the object to which the call applies is the object (call it x) under construction or destruction, the function called is the final overrider in the constructor’s or destructor’s class and not one overriding it in a more-derived class.

т.е. при создании или уничтожении, виртуальная функция текущего создаваемого или уничтожаемого объекта рассматривается как последняя переопределенная в иерархии.

> Понятно, что чистый виртуальный метод не сможем вызвать...

На самом деле можем:

> Member functions can be called from a constructor (or destructor) of an abstract class; the effect of making a virtual call (10.3) to a pure virtual function directly or indirectly for the object being created (or destroyed) from such a constructor (or destructor) is undefined.

Разберем цитату на примере:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    Base()
    {
        bar();//bar вызовет функцию член Base::foo, даже если её определения нет
    }
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    void bar() 
    {
        //Если bar вызвана из конструктора или деструктора, то
        foo();//виртуальный вызов приводит к вызову Base::foo()
        //Однако, т.к. объект находится в процессе создания, 
        //то, согласно цитате выше, результат такого вызова неопределен
    }
};


struct Derived: 
    Base
{
    Derived() {
        bar();//"Внутренности" Derived уже созданы, 
        //вызов foo в bar вызов приведет к вызову Derived:foo

        Base::foo();//Явный вызов Base::foo
        //подъобъект Base уже создан, поэтому такой вызов приведет к
        //вызову Base::foo, и, если её определения нет, 
        //то это приведет к неопределенному поведению
    }
    void foo() override 
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::foo()" << std::endl;
    };
};


//Чистая виртуальная функция может иметь определение, но вне класса:
void Base::foo()
{
    std::cout << "Base::foo()" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    delete new Derived();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда конструируется объект (базового класса), он не знает еще о существовании производных от него классов. Поэтому его финальная переопределенная виртуальная функция и будет той функцией, которая будет вызвана из конструктора или деструктора.

Рассмотрите следующий простой пример.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A()
    {
        f();
    }

    ~A()
    {
        g();
    }

    virtual void f()
    {
        std::cout << "A::f()\n";
    }

    virtual void g()
    {
        std::cout << "A::g()\n";
    }

};

struct B : virtual A
{
    B()
    {
        f();
    }

    ~B()
    {
        g();
    }

    virtual void f() override
    {
        std::cout << "B::f()\n";
    }

    virtual void g() override
    {
        std::cout << "B::g()\n";
    }
};

int main() 
{
    B b;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
A::f()
B::f()
B::g()
A::g()
```

Итак, в программе создается объект `b` класса `B`:

```
B b;
```

Класс `B` имеет базовый класс `A`. Поэтому при создании объекта `b` сначала создается его подобъект типа struct `A`. То есть сначала вызывается конструктор базового класса `A`, создавая подобъект этого класса объекта `b`. Но этот подобъект ничего не знает о том, что он явkяется частью создаваемого объекта `b`. Поэтому он не может воспользоваться таблицей виртуальных функций класса `B`. Он в конструкторе и деструкторе использует свою таблицу виртуальных функций, то есть таблицу виртуальных функций класса `A`, в которой записан указатель на его собственные виртуальные функции, которые он и вызывает, а не переопределенные функции класса  `B`, о которых  ничего в данный момент неизвестно.